# Android default button styling not working

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm trying to set up my styles to make all buttons a particular color combination, specifically blue with white text.  Here's my main styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.DarkToolbar">
        <!-- various items -->

        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- a couple of other styles -->

    <style name="ButtonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">19sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryTextContrast</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And in the manifest:

```
 <application
        android:name=".CustomApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/application_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

`color/primary` is dark blue, and `color/primaryTextContrast` is white.  On Lollipop, the button looks perfect. On a 4.1 device, it's light gray with black text.  Every resource I've found for doing this looks exactly like what I'm doing so I don't know what I'm missing here.

I'm having a similar issue with controlling text size in the base style definition as well.

Update: here are the colors.

```
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="dark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="accent">#FFCA28</color>
    <color name="background">@android:color/white</color>
    <!-- Color for text displayed on top of the primary or dark color -->
    <color name="primaryTextContrast">@android:color/white</color>
    <!-- Color for text displayed on the background color (which I think will always be white) -->
    <color name="basicText">@color/primary</color>
    <!-- Color for text displayed on the accent color -->
    <color name="accentText">#303F9F</color>
</resources>
```

Here's v19/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.DarkToolbar.TranslucentStatus">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Here's v21:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="CustomTheme">
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
        <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I don't think either of these is what's making it work properly on 5.1.

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my galaxy s3 mini (Android 4.1), are you sure you don't have two versions of styles.xml, and the one with this code is > v16 ?

Comment: I have two versions, but this is the one in main/res/values.

Comment: @Jones I added my additional style files.

Answer (score 13):

Using AppCompat `22.1.+` (`22.2.0` should work too), I defined a Style like this:

```
<style name="MyApp.Button.Red" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

and then applied the theme in a button using the native `theme` attribute from `android` namespace, as said in [this](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) awesome post from Chris Banes.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/sign_up_button"
    android:theme="@style/MyApp.Button.Red" />
```

Comment: `android:textColor` is already defined in the theme, why are you defining again in Button declaration.

Comment: Isn't there a way to alter the style of all buttons in the app so I don't have to set anything on every button?  I thought these style files were supposed to be capable of that.

Comment: Because of some unknown reason, when setting it in theme, the background color doesn't work properly. Probably because defining it into the app theme suppies it as a `style` attribute, instead of `theme`. I hope getting this fixed soon.

Comment: You mean you hope to find a solution soon, or you hope Google fixes it soon?

Comment: Seems to be a library fault, as when setting in app theme, the button fits visual, text appearance, but don't get the background color properly.

Comment: Although to me this is not a viable option as it'd require that I go through the entire app that I already have and change every `Button`, up until this moment this is the only working solution that I've found. I seriously hope that Google fixes this bug soon.

Comment: Found a solution to this, just add `buttonStyle` without the `android:` prefix, example code in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I tried adding `buttonStyle` without the `android:` prefix and it solved the problem. Yeah, weird.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I had no luck with your solution. All styles works, except the button background color.

Comment: I'm working on something else at the moment but I'll give this a try, thanks.

Comment: You just saved my life! Worked for me:     

> compileSdkVersion 27 <

       > minSdkVersion 22 <
        
> targetSdkVersion 27 <

Answer (score -2):

gradle:`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'`

For theme to work properly in android lollipop, you need to extend 
**ActionBarActivity**instead of **Activity**.
By doing this change,your theme setting should work properly.
This is general for other people that for lower version of android,you should not use **android:** tag in item-name definition
`

Comment: I'm extending AppCompatActivity... can you provide some supporting documentation, because that sounds really weird that themes wouldn't work unless you extend ActionBarActivity.

Comment: I know its weird but after hours of debugging,I found that extending ActionBarActivity did the job for me.When I was extending Activity,Theme.AppCompat wasn't displaying Actionbar.So I thought it might do the work for you

Comment: I don't think this is the answer for me since ActionBarActivity is deprecated and replaced with AppCompatActivity, which is what I'm using.  Thanks though.